# How to I include command modifiers in a Process()?

Tags: swift, macos, tar

**Goal:** I'm attempting to zip a file via a swift script.

I want to zip a folder via a Swift script like the following (at the prompt):

```
$~/workarea:ls
MyStuff/
$~/workarea:tar -cf MyStuff.zip MyStuff
$~/workarea:ls
MyStuff/    MyStuff.zip
$~/workarea:
```

Here's the Swift script:

```
import Foundation

let workArea = "/Users/Ric/workarea"

extension Process {
    private static let tarExecURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/tar")

    public func zip(source: String, archivedOutput: String) throws {
        executableURL = Process.tarExecURL
        arguments = ["-cf", archivedOutput, source]
        // emulate this: $~/workarea:tar -cf MyStuff.zip MyStuff
        try run()
    }

}

// ============================================================================================

func zipFolder() {
   // let sourceURL = URL(string:workArea+"MyStuff")
    let source = workArea+"/"+"MyStuff"
    let output = workArea+"/"+"MyStuff.zip"
    try! Process().zip(source: source, archivedOutput: output)
    print("Finished Archive")
}

// ============================================================================================

zipFolder()

print("Done")
```

I used the absolute path to the member files:

```
(lldb) po source
"/Users/Ric/workarea/MyStuff"

(lldb) po output
"/Users/Ric/workarea/MyStuff.zip"
```

But tar complained about the '/'.

I'm getting the following error in the console:

```
Finished Archive
Done
tar: Removing leading '/' from member names
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

**Solution?**

Answer (score 1):

You are including `tar` twice, once as a command, then again as an argument. It should be:

```
arguments = ["-cf", archivedOutput, source]
```

Once you remove the redundant `tar` you should get the output:

```
Finished Archive
Done
```

**EDIT**: The "workArea" path should include a trailing forward-slash:

```
let workArea = "/Users/Ric/workarea/"
```

Otherwise you'll end up with paths that look like:

```
/Users/Ric/workareaMyStuff.zip
```

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee: I'm not sure I follow, your command is currently setup to do: `/usr/bin/tar tar -cf <output> <source>` — notice the redundant `tar` (as an argument).

Comment: Thanks for you correct assessment.  I made the adjustment per your query.   Now I got the another problem per restated Question.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee: It should be `let workArea = "/Users/Ric/workarea/"` (with a trailing forward slash) on line `3`

Comment: All appears to be okay now.